# Can't install Frontpage 98 on Windows Vista; disk just spins

Tags: windows-vista, frontpage

I want to install front page editor 98 onto my computer. a year ago it worked, but now it just wont install after i has to reinstall the entire OS to factory state.

I click Install Frontpage 98 but the disk just spins around and nothing else happens.
What's going on?

-EDIT: I rebooted the laptop and installed fine!

Comment: For the love of god why?

Comment: Is the disk itself OK? Try copying all the files from it to the hard disk; if it has any problems doing that, it's quite possible that the same problem affects the installer as well.

Comment: @Shutupsquare i like this editor for creating webpages